# Java Unit testing Google AppEngine memcache standalone

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit, memcached

I'm attempting to write unit tests for my Java AppEngine application around my caching service.  Any time I make a get or put I get the following exception:

> *Can't make API call memcache.Get in a thread that is neither the*
>   *original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager*

My implementation is simple enough:

```
MemcacheServiceFactory.getAsyncMemcacheService(NAMESPACE).get("key")
MemcacheServiceFactory.getAsyncMemcacheService(NAMESPACE).put("key", "value")
```

I have also tried:

```
MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService(NAMESPACE).get("key")
MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService(NAMESPACE).put("key", "value")
```

This works just fine when I'm running it as a "local deployment" as part of my web service as a whole, but the standalone test on this section of code will not work.

Is there any way to test the memcache service stand alone - outside of the gae envirnment?

Comment: Any reason why you are not mocking this call ?

Comment: Mostly because I'm trying to run integration tests through a couple different services

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized LocalServiceTestHelper like that?

```
private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
  new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalMemcacheServiceTestConfig());
```

Here you can find an example:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/unittests/src/test/java/com/google/appengine/samples/LocalMemcacheTest.java